# what is the convention for a django apps file structure

Tags: python, django

I have seen two structures so far but am not sure which is considered the convention:

- [app]

  - static
  - media

or

- [app]

  - static

    - media

Where is the correct place to put media files in Django?

Comment: By media do you mean user-uploaded content? That typically is not stored with the application. See the MEDIA_ROOT setting.

Comment: i mean js and css files mostly

Comment: JS and CSS are usually considered static assets.

Comment: ok, so what would typically go in the media dir?

Comment: User or admin uploadable content. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/files/.

Comment: And I'm not sure where you saw those two structures, they are not typical.

Comment: thanks, so back to the original question, where should that media be stored?

Comment: Again, see the MEDIA_ROOT setting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the structure described here http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html